# stacked graphs with Dygraphs

Tags: dygraphs, stacked

I'm trying to create a stacked graphs with Dygraphs using "stackedGraph: true".
When I have hard copied data to html file, everything works great:
exp:

> ```
>     var gStacked = new Dygraph(
>         document.getElementById("Stacked"),
>     "X,Y,Z\n"+ 
>       "1,3,5\n"+ 
>       "2,5,4\n"+ 
>       "3,2,7\n",
>         {
>             title: "Stacked",
>             xlabel: 'Date/Time',
>             ylabel: 'Messages',
>             stackedGraph: true,
>             drawCallback: function(g, is_initial) {
>                 if (!is_initial) return;
>                         showHideSeries(9);
>              },
>         });
> ```

when I try to read data from csv file, stackedGraph doesn't work
exp:

> ```
>     var gStacked = new Dygraph(
>         document.getElementById("Stacked"),
>     "Read.csv", // path to CSV file 
>         {
>             title: "Stacked",
>             xlabel: 'Date/Time',
>             ylabel: 'Messages',
>             stackedGraph: true,
>             drawCallback: function(g, is_initial) {
>                 if (!is_initial) return;
>                         showHideSeries(9);
>              },
>         });
> ```

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are there any errors in your JS console? Often this indicates that your web server is configured in a way that prevents `Read.csv` from being served.

Comment: if the problem is solved, please post the solution as an answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

The problem was a var with commonOptions that had stackedGraphs as false. when I commented out this, everything worked great.